# Serialize GeoQuerySet as JSON in Django REST?

Tags: json, django, rest, geo

I am trying to serialize a GeoQuerySet to JSON using the Django REST Framework. I'm new to Django and know very little about databases in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have been trying to solve this problem for a whole day now.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```py
class PointView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyEntityModelSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Enter description
        here
        """

        entity=EntityType.objects.exclude(point=None)[0]
        lon=request.data['lng']
        lat=request.data['lat']
        radius_km=request.data['radius_km']
        within_radius=entity.is_near(lat,lon,radius_km)

        return within_radius
```

And here is my error message:

```
AssertionError at /point/

Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'django.contrib.gis.db.models.query.GeoQuerySet'>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution!  It turns out that POST is designed for updates to data, and I simply wanted to GET data.

The Django REST Framework (DRF), is built to standards, and so the behavior I was trying to force was not something the framework had been designed to do.

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```py
class PointView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyEntityModelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
       """
        Enter description
        here
        """

        params = self.request.query_params

        entity=EntityType.objects.exclude(point=None)[0]
        lon=float(params['lng'])
        lat=float(params['lat'])
        radius_km=float(params['radius_km'])
        within_radius=entity.is_near(lat, lon, radius_km)

        return within_radius
```

Thank you to bibhas and tbaxter on irc.freenode.net/django who pointed out the error in my thinking: GET-Styled POST-Requests are *so not HTTP/1.1*.